# React State not updating until I refresh the page manualy

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, rtk-query

in a React App which I have to use redux, I'm trying to change a button link "Sign in" into " Log Out " when a token is in Cookies.
but the state "isLogged" doesn't update , but it update only when I refresh the page manually.

How can I do that automatically ?

Here is the code for that:

```js
const token = Cookies.get("token");
const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (token) {
    setIsLogged(true);
  }
}, [token]);

const handleLogout = () => {
  Cookies.remove("token");
  setIsLogged(false);
  console.log("logout");
};
```

Here is the code for the token which I get correctly in the `signIn` page:

```js
// call api
const [getToken, { isLoading, isError }] = useGetTokenMutation();

// handle submit
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  getToken({ email, password })
    .unwrap() // Récupère le résultat du token de la promesse
    .then((data) => {
      const token = data.body.token;
      Cookies.set("token", token, { expires: 1 });
      navigate("/users");
      setErrorMessage("");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setShakingAnimation(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setShakingAnimation(false);
      }, 500);
      setErrorMessage(error.data.message);
    });
};
```

And here is the API slice from redux:

```js
export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:3001/api/v1/",
  }),
  tagTypes: ["User"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getToken: builder.mutation({
      query: (user) => ({
        url: "user/login",
        method: "POST",
        body: user,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["User"],
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetTokenMutation } = apiSlice;
```

[Link Github project](https://github.com/maxdnc/ArgentBank-website/blob/main/Front-end/argentbank/src/layout/Head.jsx)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't update is that your component is not getting a trigger to re-render unless the parent component re-renders or you hit the refresh.
It would be a good idea to create an `authSlice` and maintain `isLoggedIn` state in the store. Once you have a token, dispatch the action to update `isLoggedIn` state. This, in turn, would re-render the component.

It's a good idea to maintain isLoggedIn state in the reducer instead of useState.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah yes i see! I'm not familiar with redux : should i do this way for authSlice: ; const authSlice = createSlice({ name: 'auth', initialState: { isLoggedIn: false, }, reducers: { setLoggedIn: (state, action) => { state.isLoggedIn = action.payload; }, }, }); export const { setLoggedIn } = authSlice.actions; export default authSlice.reducer; – "  then dispatch(setLoggedIn(true)) in handleSubmit . Then const isLogged = useSelector((state) in head ?

Comment: That's the idea. 
useSelector(state) --> assuming that you  weren't able to write the whole code snippet here.

Take a look at redux docs. https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start

Just follow along and you will be able to figure it out.

Comment: thanks it work ! i just don"t understand; can you  explain to me why the useEffect was not updating the state ?

Comment: useEffect doesn't watch for changes in external dependencies like cookies. For useEffect to respond to changes in cookie values, you will have to write some sort of subscription/watchers to trigger the effect, which wouldn't be a clean approach.